# Why does my marge definition take the full width on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I have clearly defined my parameters and functions but for some reason my `typewrite__clip` takes the full width on load.  Image below, then the line pops on the same plane as the 'of' and the red bar is no longer far to the right.

Does anyone know what the fix is?

[image: The problem child]

Here is the css and the jQuery

```js
<script>
 // Jquery TypeWriter
 // Jquery TypeWriter
  // Jquery TypeWriter

  (function ($) {

    var defaultsParams = {
        speed: 1000,
        delay: 2000,
        marge: 10
    };

    $.fn.typewriter = function (options) {
        var $this = $(this);

        return this.each(function () {
            $this = $(this);

            new TypeWriter($this, options);
        });
    };

    function TypeWriter(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.params = defaultsParams;
        this.nextWord = null;

        $.extend(this.params, defaultsParams, options);
        this.init();
    }

    /**
     * Init classes
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.init = function () {
        this.element.find('p:not(:first)').addClass('u-invisible');
        this.element.find('p:first').addClass('u-visible');

        this.activeItem = this.nextWord = this.getVisibleItem();
        this.showWord(0);
    };

    /**
     * Show word
     * @param initSpeed
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.showWord = function (initSpeed) {
        var _this = this,
            width = this.nextWord.width(),
            speed = (initSpeed != undefined) ? initSpeed : this.params.speed;

        this.activeItem = this.nextWord;

        this.element.animate({
            width: width + this.params.marge + 'px'
        }, speed, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                _this.hideWord();
            }, _this.params.delay);
        });
    };

    /**
     * Hide word
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.hideWord = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.nextWord = this.getNextWord();

        this.element.animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, this.params.speed, function () {
            _this.updateClasses();
            _this.showWord();
        });
    };

    /**
     * Return Active item
     * @returns {*}
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.getNextWord = function () {
        return (this.activeItem.is(':last-child')) ? this.element.children().eq(0) : this.activeItem.next();

    };

    /**
     * Switch classes
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.updateClasses = function () {
        this.nextWord.addClass('u-visible').removeClass('u-invisible');
        this.activeItem.addClass('u-invisible').removeClass('u-visible');
    };

    /**
     * Get current active item
     */
    TypeWriter.prototype.getVisibleItem = function () {
        return this.element.find('p:visible').first();
    };

})(jQuery);

$('.js-typewriter').typewriter();

  </script>
```

```css
    .type{
    padding-top: 3.245em;
    margin-left: -5em;
    }

    .type h1{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1em;
    }

    .typewriter__clip {
    width: auto;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Domine', serif;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 6px;
    border-right: 6px solid #ed2024;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: -1em;
    }

    .typewriter__clip p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 55px!important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 65px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .typewriter__clip p.u-visible {
    position: relative;
    }

    .u-invisible {
    opacity: 0;
    }

    .u-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="type">
<h1>The art + science
of</h1>
<div class="typewriter__clip js-typewriter">

acquiring new residents

promoting awesome activites

keeping families informed

showcasing delicious menus

enriching a resident's life

making the ultimate impression

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should look for [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rules for `typewriter__clip p` in order to adapt the `font-size: 55px!important;` to smaller screens.

Comment: I already did though :) at media only screen and (max-width: 769px) .typewriter__clip p {
   font-size: 35px!important;
  }